# Text Editor For Flash?

Tags: flash, text-editor, wysiwyg

I work for a company which produces flash websites. The CMS is built in PHP. The client can update the text on the CMS site. Currently it uses a really old, bad, flash text-editor. It needs to be upgraded to something much much better.

I need a text editor that will produce 'flash-html' as well as 'valid-html'. Or even something that marks up the text in the way that would allow me to do this.

I tried using TinyMCE and ran into problems trying to convert the HTML.

Has anyone tried doing this?

Can anyone recommend anything or give any tips on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "Flash-HTML" you mean "the appropriate subset of HTML supported by Flash in their textfields" and, unless there's something I am completely misunderstanding, TinyMCE is capable of controlling each of these tags.

You haven't said in which way TinyMCE is not applicable, so I am going to further assume that the problem is it offers control of HTML features not in the Flash-HTML subset. If that is indeed the case, you should have a look at [a demo of TinyMCE in action](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_04.php), where the top instance allows you control of only formatting and the source demonstrates how to add/remove options from the control bar.

You may also wish to consider [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (try checking out their [Customer Toolbar demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) [for which you'll need to click on the appropriate button]).

Ultimately, any HTML WYSIWG editor should work as a solution in your case (and notably you never actually told us what your problem was.)